# Tumblr : retrieve a specific tag via JS

Tags: javascript, css, tags, tumblr

I do not anything much about JS. However I would like to be able to trigger a specific stylesheet depending on the tag in a photoset post.

More precisely, for a photo gallery, I would like to  have a default css and then, when adding the tag "slideshow", offer a different style.

I'm not sure whether this can be done. Haven't really understood their API. What do you think ?

https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

Thank you

Comment: use their api client: https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.js and I guess after setting up you could run a query for tagged posts under the certain tag you need and run some logic like: if the post is in the response add stylesheet and if it isn't do something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `.addclass()`.

Assuming your photos are of class `.photo`

```
$('.photo').addClass('slideshow');
```

and then when you dont want the special css anymore

```
$('.photo').removeClass('slideshow');
```

Thus `.photo` will be your default css class and `.slideshow` will be added by your jQuery.
You could then switch between them with an `if else` statement.

```
if (1 = 1) {
        $('.photo').addClass('slideshow');
    } else {
        $('.photo').removeClass('slideshow');
    }
```